# Oracle: TABLE ACCESS FULL with Primary key?

Tags: oracle10g

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
   IDR decimal(9) NOT NULL,
   IDS decimal(9) NOT NULL,
   DT date NOT NULL,
   VAL decimal(10) NOT NULL,
   AFFID decimal(9),
   CONSTRAINT PKtemp PRIMARY KEY (IDR,IDS,DT)
)
;
```

Let's see the plan for select star query:

```
SQL>explain plan for select * from temp;

Explained.

SQL> select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'serial'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation     | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |   |     1 |    61 |     2   (0)|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEMP |     1 |    61 |     2   (0)|
---------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version

11 rows selected.
```

SQL server 2008 shows in the same situation Clustered index scan. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select * with no where clause -- means read every row in the table, fetch every column.

What do you gain by using an index?  You have to go to the index, get a rowid, translate the rowid into a table offset, read the file.

What happens when you do a full table scan?  You go the th first rowid in the table, then read on through the table to the end.

Which one of these is faster given the table you have above?  Full table scan.  Why? because it skips having to to go the index, retreive values, then going back to the other to where the table lives and fetching.

Comment: fine, but why guys from microsoft are using clustered index scan if there is no reason for that?

Comment: @tim, a clustered index is kept in the data blocks (in SQL Server -- other engines may differ), so there's no overhead using it wrt a plain full table scan.

Comment: thanx Alex, reasonable answer

Comment: Plus, a Full Table Scan can read the data using multiblock reads.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this more simply without mumbo-jumbo, the reason is:

```
Clustered Index = Table
```

That's by definition in SQL Server. If this is not clear, look up the definition.

To be absolutely clear once again, since most people seem to miss this, the Clustered Index *IS* the table itself. It therefore follows that "Clustered Index Scan" is another way of saying "Table Scan". Or what Oracle calls "TABLE ACCESS FULL"